# Display array in textboxes in a while loop

Tags: java, arrays, swing, awt

I am creating a program that will take the data from several textboxes store in an array and when a next and previous button are pressed display the next or last position in the array, currently the next button gets stuck in a while loop without displaying and I'm not sure how to fix it, I am an amateur and I need help with this.

```
package major;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.Label;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class gui {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField websitetxt;
    private JTextField usernametxt;
    private JTextField passwordtxt;
    private encryptedData[] dataArray;
    private int dataArrayMaxIndex;
    private int dataArrayMax;
    private int dataArrayCurrentIndex;
    private JButton btnadd;
    private JButton btnnew;
    private JButton btndelete;
    private JTextField notestxt;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    gui window = new gui();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public gui() {
        initialize();
        dataArrayMax = 20;
        dataArray = new encryptedData[dataArrayMax];
        dataArrayMaxIndex = 0;
        while (dataArrayMaxIndex < dataArrayMax) {
            dataArray[dataArrayMaxIndex] = new encryptedData();
            dataArrayMaxIndex++;
        }
        dataArrayMaxIndex = -1;
        dataArrayCurrentIndex = -1;

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 569, 427);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        websitetxt = new JTextField();
        websitetxt.setBounds(315, 56, 191, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(websitetxt);
        websitetxt.setColumns(10);

        usernametxt = new JTextField();
        usernametxt.setColumns(10);
        usernametxt.setBounds(315, 105, 191, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(usernametxt);

        passwordtxt = new JTextField();
        passwordtxt.setColumns(10);
        passwordtxt.setBounds(315, 154, 191, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(passwordtxt);

        JLabel lblWebsite = new JLabel("Website:");
        lblWebsite.setBounds(227, 68, 78, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblWebsite);

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
        lblUsername.setBounds(227, 117, 78, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
        lblPassword.setBounds(227, 166, 78, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

        final JButton btnadd = new JButton("Add to Database");
        btnadd.setEnabled(false);
        btnadd.setBounds(10, 105, 191, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnadd);

        JLabel lblPasswordManagerHsc = new JLabel("Password manager hsc 2014");
        lblPasswordManagerHsc.setBounds(191, 11, 168, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPasswordManagerHsc);

        final JButton btnnew = new JButton("New Record");

        btnnew.setBounds(10, 56, 191, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnnew);

        JButton btndelete = new JButton("Delete Record");

        btndelete.setBounds(10, 154, 191, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btndelete);

        JButton btnprev = new JButton("Prev");
        btnprev.setBounds(315, 316, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnprev);

        JButton btnnext = new JButton("Next");
        btnnext.setBounds(417, 316, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnnext);

        notestxt = new JTextField();
        notestxt.setBounds(315, 203, 191, 102);
        frame.getContentPane().add(notestxt);
        notestxt.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblnotes = new JLabel("Notes");
        lblnotes.setBounds(227, 215, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblnotes);

        JButton btngenerate = new JButton("Generate Password");
        btngenerate.setBounds(10, 203, 191, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btngenerate);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu File = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(File);

        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        File.add(save);

        JMenuItem load = new JMenuItem("Load");
        File.add(load);

        JMenuItem mntmHelp = new JMenuItem("About");
        File.add(mntmHelp);

        websitetxt.setEnabled(false);
        usernametxt.setEnabled(false);
        passwordtxt.setEnabled(false);
        notestxt.setEnabled(false);

        btnadd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                btnadd.setEnabled(false);
                dataArrayCurrentIndex++;
                dataArrayMaxIndex++;
                dataArray[dataArrayCurrentIndex].username = usernametxt.getText();
                dataArray[dataArrayCurrentIndex].password = passwordtxt.getText();
                dataArray[dataArrayCurrentIndex].notes = notestxt.getText();
                dataArray[dataArrayCurrentIndex].website = websitetxt.getText();
            }
        });

        btnnew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == btnnew) {
                    websitetxt.setEnabled(true);
                    usernametxt.setEnabled(true);
                    passwordtxt.setEnabled(true);
                    notestxt.setEnabled(true);
                    btnadd.setEnabled(true);
                    websitetxt.setText("");
                    usernametxt.setText("");
                    passwordtxt.setText("");
                    notestxt.setText("");

                }
            }
        });

        btndelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });

        btnprev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        btnnext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < dataArrayMaxIndex) {
                    dataArrayCurrentIndex = i;
                    websitetxt.setText(dataArray[i].getWebsitename());
                    usernametxt.setText(dataArray[i].getUsername());
                    passwordtxt.setText(dataArray[i].getPassword());
                    notestxt.setText(dataArray[i].getNotes());
                }
                i++;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
package major;

public class encryptedData {

    public String website;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String notes;

    public encryptedData() {
        try {
            website = "";
            username = "";
            password = "";
            notes = "";
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public encryptedData(String w, String u, String p, String n) {
        try {
            website = w;
            username = u;
            password = p;
            notes = n;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    //Access methods
    public String getWebsitename() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsiteName(String w) {
        website = w;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String u) {
        username = u;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password + "";
    }

    public void setPassword(String p) {
        password = p;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes + "";
    }

    public void setNotes(String n) {
        notes = n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing i *after* the while loop in `actionPerformed()`!

If you had formatted your code better, this would have been obvious:

```
btnnext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i<dataArrayMaxIndex) {
            dataArrayCurrentIndex = i;
            websitetxt.setText(dataArray[i].getWebsitename());
            usernametxt.setText(dataArray[i].getUsername());
            passwordtxt.setText(dataArray[i].getPassword());
            notestxt.setText(dataArray[i].getNotes());
        }
        i++;
    }
});
```

And this would have been even better:

```
btnnext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i<dataArrayMaxIndex; i++) {
            dataArrayCurrentIndex = i;
            websitetxt.setText(dataArray[i].getWebsitename());
            usernametxt.setText(dataArray[i].getUsername());
            passwordtxt.setText(dataArray[i].getPassword());
            notestxt.setText(dataArray[i].getNotes());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for illustrating the importance of formatting. It's not just to make the code look pretty. 1+

Comment: Awesome cyber sam thank you very much! My formatting is pretty bad my SDD teacher never really taught us how to make it neat ETC so ive been trying to get it neater on my own. thanks for suffering through it :)